# Regular Expression, check of substring at position

Tags: regex

I have these 2 strings:

- 00000000000008165736
- RF77706578000000000543278

I need a regular expression that checks **at position 15 that the next 3 characters are 657** or **at position 6 the next 3 character are 657**

This needs to be one regular expression that matches both strings.

I 've been working on something like this **^.{15}(.{3})|^.{6}(.{3})** but I can't straight it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```regex
^(?:.{6}657|.{15}657)
```

### Demo

This regex says to match:

```regex
^   from the start of the string
(?:
    .{6}657   657 starting at the 7th character
    |         OR
    .{15}657  657 starting at the 16th character
)
```

Comment: Did you mean `^(?:.{6}657|.{15}657)` as in your demo?

Answer (score 0):

`^(.{6}|.{15})657`

For a demo you can see here:
https://regex101.com/r/Aj0qG8/1